# Dropwizard Liquibase, run db migrate.xml file, which is inside of jar

Tags: mysql, jar, liquibase, dropwizard, microservices

I need run my dropwizard jar in the linux server.
Configuration files inside of jar. When I am using maven in my dev, all ok.
I have problem for both:liquibase  and dropwizard configuration files.
For dropwizard when I put config outside of jar

```
java -jar myapp.jar server config.yml
```

it is ok, app. strated, but does not executed  liquibase migration, which configs I have in pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>
                        ${basedir}/src/main/resources/migrations.xml
                    </changeLogFile>
                    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/twitterdb</url>
                    <username>root</username>
                    <password>root</password>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I downloaded liquibase, extracted, set liquibase home as ENV.

now I try to run

```
java -jar liquibase/liquibase.jar --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --changeLogFile=migratedb.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/twitterDB" --username=root --password=root update .
```

but in this case liquibase did not find mysql driver.

Basically I want start project using configs files which is inside of jar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

add set the classpath to the dir where the driver is installed

```
--classpath=<value> Classpath containing migration files and JDBC Driver.
```

Comment: I did it: java -jar liquibase/liquibase.jar --classpath=liquibase/mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --changeLogFile=liquibase/migrate.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/twitetrdb" --username=root --password=root update